# Return io.ReadCloser from zip.NewWriter

Tags: go

I am creating a buffer and then writing into that buffer via zip.NewWriter()

So my code looks like this

```
// Create a buffer to write our archive to.
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

// Create a new zip archive.
w := zip.NewWriter(buf)

// Create file in this writer
f, err := w.Create("test.json")

/ Writing data to file
_, _ = f.Write([]byte("some data"))

// Close writer
_ =  w.Close()

// TODO: Return this data in the form of io.ReadCloser
```

My end goal is to write files into this zip writer and return the data in the form of io.ReadCloser, my calling function expects data in io.ReadCloser

I tried to find and try multiple ways but none of them succeeded.

Comment: If you already closed it, do you need a ReadCloser?

Comment: Hi @CeriseLimón Thanks for your suggestion, its really io.ReadCloser, I miss-typed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some help from comments I got it working
So we can directly convert buf to io.ReadCloser and return it, no need for further conversion.

```
func ExampleWriter() (io.ReadCloser, error) {
// Create a buffer to write our archive to.
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

// Create a new zip archive.
w := zip.NewWriter(buf)

// Add some files to the archive.
var files = []struct {
    Name, Body string
}{
    {"readme.txt", "This archive contains some text files."},
    {"gopher.txt", "Gopher names:\nGeorge\nGeoffrey\nGonzo"},
    {"todo.txt", "Get animal handling licence.\nWrite more examples."},
}
for _, file := range files {
    f, err := w.Create(file.Name)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, err = f.Write([]byte(file.Body))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

// Make sure to check the error on Close.
err := w.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

return ioutil.NopCloser(buf), nil // This returns io.ReadCloser
```

}

Comment: To make an answer that would be useful to anyone else, it's important to indicate *what* was changed and *why* that fixed it, rather than simply printing a new block of code with no explanation.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian for your suggestion, I have added the details of what made this solution work and solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Check if [this example](https://github.com/Phenom-OS/build_soong/blob/ddcaa3bf0f3dd315a1502e72d4096d576f7828c2/third_party/zip/example_test.go#L17-L48) works for you

```golang
func ExampleWriter() {
    // Create a buffer to write our archive to.
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    // Create a new zip archive.
    w := zip.NewWriter(buf)

    // Add some files to the archive.
    var files = []struct {
        Name, Body string
    }{
        {"readme.txt", "This archive contains some text files."},
        {"gopher.txt", "Gopher names:\nGeorge\nGeoffrey\nGonzo"},
        {"todo.txt", "Get animal handling licence.\nWrite more examples."},
    }
    for _, file := range files {
        f, err := w.Create(file.Name)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        _, err = f.Write([]byte(file.Body))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }

    // Make sure to check the error on Close.
    err := w.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

By systematically check the error for those operations, you will see if there are any issue.